# Swing: How to get JComponent from its editor

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jcomponent

How would you in general get `JComponent` from its editor?

**Example:**

Let's have editable `JComboBox`. The combo therefore has an editor (`JTextField` by default).

```
JComboBox b = new JComboBox();
b.setEditable(true);
```

Now add 'global' keyboard listener to Swing application.

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(
        new AWTEventListener() {
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e) {
                JComponent c = (JComponent) e.getSource();
                System.out.println(c); // <- printing the event source
            }
        },
        AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
```

The output of typing text to combo box `b` shows, that the source of the key events is `b`'s editor, not the combo box `b` itself:

```
javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxEditor$1[,0,0, ...
javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxEditor$1[,0,0, ...
javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalComboBoxEditor$1[,0,0, ...
...
```

Is there a way to get reference to `b` from its editor or from key event?
If no, how can I get the reference of 'currently editing combo box'?

P.S.: Please don't ask me questions like "why would you need it?". Thanks.

Comment: :) why we should not ask 'why would you need it?' ? what does `getParent()` returns in your case?

Comment: I can't resist to ask: why would you need that?

Comment: *Please don't ask me questions like "why would you need it?"* Must be Top Secret eh? Its better to give us an understanding of exactly what you are trying to achieve, so we can give appropriate solutions.

Comment: whats reason to suply  ListSelection Listener with AWTEventListener

Answer (score 2):

Invoke `getEditorComponent()`. This method is defined in interface `ComboBoxEditor`:

```
public interface ComboBoxEditor {

  /** Return the component that should be added to the tree hierarchy for
    * this editor
    */
  public Component getEditorComponent();
  ................
```

so cast it to `ComboBoxEditor` first:

```
Component component = (ComboBoxEditor)event.getSource()).getEditorComponent();
```